# DEPRECATION WARNING: [paperclip] [deprecation] AWS SDK v1 has been deprecated in paperclip 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Recently I migrated my Rails version from 3.2 to 4.2.6 and along with that I modify some gems like paperclip 2.3 to 4.3.6. When I run rails server, I am getting following deprecations:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: [paperclip] [deprecation] AWS SDK v1 has been
>   deprecated in paperclip 5. Please consider upgrading to AWS 2 before
>   upgrading paperclip. (called from  at
>   /home/myuser/Desktop/project/app/models/user.rb:58) DEPRECATION
>   WARNING: [paperclip] [deprecation] AWS SDK v1 has been deprecated in
>   paperclip 5. Please consider upgrading to AWS 2 before upgrading
>   paperclip. (called from  at
>   /home/myuser/Desktop/project/app/models/user.rb:72)

This is user.rb, line 58:

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => { :small => "125x125>" } ,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
```

This is user.rb, line 72:

```
  has_attached_file :logo,
    :styles => { :small => "200x100>" } ,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
```

How to over come this deprecation? Please help

Comment: Do you have an aws-sdk gem?  If so that should be upgraded as well.

Comment: I am having aws-sdk gem with version 1.3.9

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using the AWS gem anywhere else in your app, then it will be pretty simple. Upgrade the AWS gem, and go through the [notes that Paperclip has provided](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/UPGRADING) to make sure the upgrade goes smoothly.

If you are using the AWS gem elsewhere, then you can either upgrade the usage manually, or you can actually have both v1 and v2 of the gem in your app. The gem provides information on [running them side-by-side](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#side-by-side-usage).